# Comunicação Assíncrona

Tags: python, socket, assincronismo, pipe

Pretendo implementar uma comunicação assíncrona privada (em python) de forma a poder testar alguns algoritmos criptográficos. O objetivo seria ter um Emmiter que envia a mensagem encriptada e ter um Receiver que recebe essa mensagem e desencripta. Neste ponto estou na dúvida se deveria usar Socket ou simplesmente um Pipe... Qual será a melhor opção?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use socket em localhost, no geral os sistemas operacionais são muito mais otimizados na parte de sockets/rede que em pipes: se bobear vai ser mais rápido o socket que o pipe. E você pode reaproveitar o código se decidir usar duas máquinas separadas.